# Twitter Rest API Read tweets from one page endpoint

Tags: twitter, twitter-rest-api

I've never used twitter before and I need to implement the Twitter Rest API. I need to read all the tweets from one page (example: [here](https://twitter.com/azure)) with my application.

Now I'm reading the documentation and I can't figure out which endpoint I have to use for this.

Can someone point me out with which endpoint I have to use?

[Documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some examples

A user timeline https://twitter.com/azure -> https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline

Your home timeline https://twitter.com/ -> https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/home_timeline

A tweet permalink https://twitter.com/Azure/status/898616738396332033 -> https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/show/id

Comment: Thank you the user timeline is the one I needed. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: When I'm using the user timeline endpoint, it returns the tweets & replies section. Is it possible to only return the Tweets section?

Comment: @stefmorren - you can specify parameter `exclude_replies` to `true` or `1`  i your request to exclude replies from the response. To exclude Retweets from response specify `include_rts` to `false` or `0`